# Promise.some() with a timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Use case - get a bunch of urls and cache the results.  The ones that complete fast (say 500ms) get incorporated on this pass, any that take longer than that still complete and get saved to cache so next time round (~10 mins later in our app) they are in cache .

I'd like to be able to do something like `Promise.someWithTimeout(promises, timeout)` where the result is an array of resolved values that completed before the timeout expired.  (`Promise.some()` is really close by it takes a count not a timeout)

Something like

```
Promise.someWithTimeout([promises], <timeout value>)
.then((results) => {
  //stuff
})
```

Where each of the promises looks like

```
return memcache.getAsync(keyFromUrl(url))
.then((cacheRes) => {
  if(cacheRes) return cacheRes;
  //not in cache go get it
  return rp(url)
  .then((rpRes) => {
    //Save to cache but don't wait for it to complete
    memcache.setAsync(keyFromUrl(url), rpRes, 86400).catch((e) => { /*error logging*/ }) 
    return rpRes;
  })
})
```

The idea being that if the url comes back fast we use it, if it takes longer we bail but still cache the result so next time through we have it.  So the `rp()` timeout would be much longer than the `Promise.someWithTimeout()` one

Has anybody written a lib to do this (I can't find one), or is there a better pattern? I though about using `Promise.all().timeout().finally()` with the promises stashing their results into an array but it doesn't feel right for reason I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: Does each pass comprise the same "bunch of urls" or can they vary from pass to pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one-off coding, you can start two separate promise chains and use a flag to see if a timeout already happened:

```
var timedOut = false;
// your regular code
Promise.all(...).then(function() {
    // cache the result, even if it came in after the timeout

    if (!timedOut) {
       // if we didn't time out, then show the response
    }
});

Promise.delay(1000).then(function() {
    timedOut = true;
    // do whatever you want to do on the timeout
});
```

---

If you want to package this functionality into one method and have the ability to access to both the fact that it timed out AND to the eventual results even after the timeout (so you could cache them, for example), then you have to resolve with something that has more than one piece of info in it.  Here's one way to allow access to both the timeout and the eventual data by resolving with an object that can contain more than one piece of info.

```
Promise.someWithTimeout = function(promiseArray, cnt, timeout) {
    var pSome = Promise.some(promiseArray, cnt).then(function(results) {
        return {status: "done", results: results};
    });
    var pTimer = Promise.delay(timeout).then(function() {
        return {status: "timeout", promise: pSome}
    });
    return Promise.race([pSome, pTimer]);
}

// sample usage
Promise.someWithTimeout(arrayOfPromises, 3, 1000).then(function(result) {
    if (result.status === "timeout") {
        // we timed out
        // the result of the data is still coming when result.promise is resolved if you still want access to it later
        result.promise.then(function(results) {
            // can still get access to the eventual results here 
            // even though there was a timeout before they arrived
        }).catch(...);
    } else {
        // result.results is the array of results from Promise.some()
    }
});
```

---

Comment: @JohnPetitt - What do you think of the options here?  Does this answer your question or give you a useful option?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense,  now I remember that a resolved promise will continue to return the same result it seems like putting all the promises int an array and then done a Promise.all(promises).then(()=> save to cache) left to run on it's own and a Promise.delay(500).then(() => return Promise.some(array)) and use the results would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Your suggestion forces a delay of 500ms even if a response comes back sooner than that.  I agree that a `Promise.all()` left to run on it's own to save in the cache makes sense.  Then, use the same promises in combination with a timer for your timeout.

Comment: @JohnPettitt - Did this solve your problem?  If so, you can indicate that to the community and earn yourself some reputation points be clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.

Comment: In the end I make a packed to do it https://github.com/jpettitt/PromiseSometime/blob/master/index.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-sometime

Comment: the `timeout` parameter is unused. Was there a reason for it?

Comment: @SamHasler - Honestly, this was 7 years ago and I don't remember the context for the `cnt` argument.  Looking at the code now, it looks like it should be `Promise.delay(timeout)` and I don't know what `cnt` was for.  Probably it came from some earlier implementation of `Promise.some()` that the OP was using in the Bluebird library.  Anyway, the concept here is that you implement a timeout by doing a `Promise.race()` between a timeout promise and your regular promise chain.